# Vscode kept auto-hiding terminal windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Have anyone seen this before? My VSCode Terminal show for a second and auto-hiding it, and stuck in a loop.

[image]

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103532, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164807, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168870